# Learning quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am in middle school. I have spent a month (about) teaching myself the basics of linear algebra. I am having geometry this year in school (I had algebra 1 last year) and I've also taught myself a bit about quantum computing. I'd like to teach myself about quantum mechanics, and I was wondering the following things:

1. Are there any other things I should study besides linear algebra? What is absolutely necessary to know?
2. What are some good resources for self-teaching quantum mechanics? I am able to read through decently complicated books; I taught myself some linear algebra out of a textbook, but also the simpler/clearer the better.

I would like to be able to handle at least a decent portion of the math behind it, as well as an intuitive understanding. I'm willing to devote a decent amount of time to this project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Absolutely necessary? just linear algebra. Very strongly recommended? at least some solid calculus that's enough to be able to do some differential equations. What's your background on those? It will help frame the question better.

Comment: How did you skip Alg 2?

Comment: @Adamawesome4, I didn't, I'm in geometry, and next year I'll be in Algebra II.